# Organizing accounts order

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, accounts, samsung-nexus-10

I have multiple emails that I usually sign-in with my android device, and I'm used to have email (A) at the top, email (B) the second, and finally email (C) at the end, but I don't know why when I finished signing-in into all of the emails email (A) were at the bottom :/

Is there's any way to organize them manually or as I want?

Note: I'm facing this problem in my nexus 10 running stock 5.0.1 & keep in mind that I also got this problem on my old Galaxy S3 before but I was running a custom ROM as I remember